# I am trying to connect to Converge Pro 2 by Clearone using NodeJS node-telnet-client but I am still not able to connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, hardware, telnet

I am using following configurations for connecting:

```
{
  host: '192.168.10.28',
  port: 23,
  shellPrompt: '=>',
  timeout: 1500,
  loginPrompt: '/Username[: ]*$/i',
  passwordPrompt: '/Password: /i',
  username: 'clearone',
  password: 'converge'
}
```

When I am trying to connect from Telnet in Windows/PuTTY, it's working fine and the output of the connection is as follows:

[image: Telnet connection string]

[image]

I think I am missing a configuration/parameter. Here is the link of the library I am using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/telnet-client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configurations add this:

```
"ors":"\r\n"
```

**Explaination:**
In telnet-client node library the default Output Record Separator is `\n` which is not working out in your case as your telnet server seems to be accepting a `\r\n` i.e. Windows style new line character after every command you issue.